# как с помощью node js добавить в html документе тег

Tags: node.js

**Вопрос 1:** Как создать в html документе(в конкретном блоке) несколько других тегов с помощью node js. (html уже размещен на сервере)

**Вопрос 1: более подробно** пример я запускаю live server на (vscode) правой кнопкой на html то есть документ уже находится на localhost:(4500) потом я хочу с помощью node js циклом for достать несколько файлов из локальной папки(умею) добавить в массив потом создать теги (src для тегов взять из массива) и эти теги передать внутрь html документа который на localhost

**Вопрос 2:** Возможно ли задать автозапуск node js кода при размещении данного html документа на сервер

Comment: Нет ни кода, ни какой-либо конкретной информации. Не понятно о чем речь. И что значит: HTML запущен на сервере? HTML - это код страницы, о не может быть запущен, запущен может быть nodejs например и то для выполнения какого-либо кода

Comment: спасибо изменил на размешен вместо запущен но тут код не нужен вроде и так понятно

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server

Ставишь:

```
npm i -g http-server
```

Запускаешь:

```
http-server /path/to/folder
```

Или запускаешь прям в папке с файлами:

```
http-server
```

Обращаю внимание, что он выставляет заголовки кэширования, так что если планируется менять статические файлы с сохранением имён, то подход так себе.

Comment: если я правильно понял то http-server просто запускает сервер это можно сделать и обычным require('http') а как достать тег из html и добавить что то в нем это и главный вопрос

Comment: Ну значит я вообще вопрос не понял.

Comment: @Armen какая задача? Сервер отдаёт эот хтмл? Или на клиенте уже есть хтмл отображенный и его надо изменить? Как этот хтмл попал клиенту? Его отдал нод сервер? Если да, то точно так же генерить новый хтмл и так же отправлять. Если хтмл генерится на клиенте, то никак с сервера ничего не дорисовать.

Comment: прояснил вопрос более подробно подробнее уже наверное не смогу надеюсь будет понятно

Comment: @AlexSazonov я правильно понял если html не находится на сервере который создан с помощью node js то достучатся до него никак?

Comment: @Armen нет. Только с клиента слать ajax, если нужно новую инфу подгрузить. А если генеришь хтмл на серваке, так просто достань всё, что тебе надо, дёрни ручку и подгрузи новый хтмл. Что-то сложности какие-то ты выдумываешь. Либо я не понимаю задачи. Мне кажется, что всё просто. Если у тебя хтмл генерится на сервере и по запросу отдаётся клиенту, то так и продолжай. Если у тебя верстка и логика на клиенте, то запрашивай json-чиками инфу и скриптом дорисовывай на клинте что хочется. 2 варианта :)

Comment: @AlexSazonov спасибо еще не до конца понял но разберусь у меня сложности с взаимодействием клиента с сервером сервер должен локальные файлы передать в клиент вот не знал как   возможно какой нить пример из инета есть на чем можно разобраться? а так добавь комент в ответах проголосую как правильный